# Swipe like Trash button Of Mail on iOS - Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, swipe

I'm working on an app, and would like the swipe was equal to swipe of Trash of Mail iOS:

[image]

My ViewController has a TableView:

[image]

And my Swift code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    var arr = [NSMutableDictionary]()

    var count:Int = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arr.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:TableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! TableViewCell
        let row = self.arr[indexPath.row]
        cell.label.text = row["name"] as? String
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .Delete {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Remove?", message: "Touch in Remove", preferredStyle: .Alert)
            let remove =  UIAlertAction(title: "Remove", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Destructive) { (UIAlertAction) -> Void in

                self.arr.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)

                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
            let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)

            alert.addAction(cancel)
            alert.addAction(remove)
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true,completion: nil)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func addAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        arr.append(["name":"row \(count)","age":"23"])
        ++count

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

}
```

When I preview the app, I see the swipe that way:

[image]

My question is: **What do I need to make my app swipe equal to swipe Mail Trash?**

Comment: Are you wanting the long swipe? As in deleting the row by swiping the width of the screen? If so, I would have a look at this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/77974/making-a-gesture-driven-to-do-list-app-like-clear-in-swift-part-1).

Comment: I want using the swipe by the end of the screen (width of screen) for call the function to remove the table row.

Comment: Look at the tutorial I linked and try something.

Answer (score -2):

You should use the delegate method

> 'titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath'

and return the string value (in your case "Trash") that you wish to display